# about ruby range?

Tags: ruby, range, each

like this

```
range = (0..10)
```

how can I get number like this:

```
0 5 10
```

plus five every time but less than 10

if range = (0..20) then i should get this:

```
0 5 10 15 20
```

Answer (score 28):

Try using [`.step()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html#M000695) to go through at a given step.

```
(0..20).step(5) do |n|
    print n,' '
end
```

gives...

```
0 5 10 15 20
```

As mentioned by dominikh, you can add `.to_a` on the end to get a storable form of the list of numbers: `(0..20).step(5).to_a`

Comment: and if you want to store the numbers you can use (0..10).step(5).to_a -- this requires ruby >= 1.8.7 though. An alternative is 0.step(10, 5).to_a, which also required ruby >= 1.8.7

Answer (score 4):

Like Dav said, but add to_a:

```
(0..20).step(5).to_a # [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]
```

Comment: You generally don’t need to add `to_a` unless you really *do* need an array.

Answer (score 2):

The `step` method described in http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html should do the job but <del>seriously harms</del> *may harm* the readability.

*Just consider:*

```
(0..20).step(5){|n| print ' first ', n }.each{|n| print ' second ',n }
```

*You may think that step(5) kind of produces a new Range, like why_*'s *question initially intended. But the each is called on the (0..20) and has to be replaced by another step(5) if you want to "reuse" the 0-5-10-15-20 range.*

Maybe you will be fine with something like `(0..3).map{|i| i*5}`?

*But* "*persisting*" *the step method's results with* `.to_a` *should also work fine*.

Comment: I'd argue that step is more readable than a map of that nature, at least in this case.

Comment: `(0..20).step(5).each{...}.each{...}` will do what you want it to do.

Comment: @Marc-Andre Lafortune: `(0..20).step(5).each{print '.'}.each{print '!'}`
will print
`.....!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!`
and that's hard to figure out at first glance - at least for me.

Comment: @efi: no, it will print .....!!!!!  Did you actually try it? The reason is that `step(5)` (with no block) returns an Enumerator that will yield 5 times. This Enumerator is returned by both `each`. What's confusing you is that `step(5){a block}` returns the original enumerable, so further `each` will operate on the full range.

Comment: @Marc-Andre Lafortune: I actually tried `(0..20).step(5).each{print '.'}.each{print '!'}` in Ruby 1.8.7 and JRuby 1.4.0. In both cases I got 5 times '.' but 20 times '!'. I tried it in IRB (and JIRB) as well as via the normal ruby interpreter. Under Linux and Windows. Strange considering your explanation...

Comment: @efi: I must have been day-dreaming. I'm very surprised. The fact that enumerator.each{} returns the base object is unintuitive for me. It's not even spec'ed in rubyspec. I'll check to see if it's only me!

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune This will do what you expect it to do: `(0..20).step(5).map{print '.'}.each{print '!'}` returns
`.....!!!!! => [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]`. `.each` will apply on the return of `.map`.