# Declaring an integer Range with step != 1 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, range

**UPDATE 2**: For posterity, this is how I've settled on doing it (thanks to Jorg's input):

```
100.step(2, -2) do |x|
    # my code
end
```

(Obviously there are plenty of ways to do this; but it sounds like this is the most "Ruby" way to do it; and that's exactly what I was after.)

---

**UPDATE**: OK, so what I was looking for was `step`:

```
(2..100).step(2) do |x|
    # my code
end
```

But it turns out that I wasn't 100% forthcoming in my original question. I actually want to iterate over this range backwards. To my surprise, a negative step isn't legal.

```
(100..2).step(-2) do |x|
    # ArgumentError: step can't be negative
end
```

So: **how do I do this backwards?**

---

I am **completely new** to Ruby, so be gentle.

Say I want to iterate over the range of even numbers from 2 to 100; how would I do that?

Obviously I *could* do:

```
(2..100).each do |x|
    if x % 2 == 0
        # my code
    end
end
```

But, *obviously* (again), that would be pretty stupid.

I know I could do something like:

```
i = 2
while i <= 100
    # my code
    i += 2
end
```

I believe I could also write my own custom class that provides its own `each` method (?). I am almost sure that would be overkill, though.

I'm interested in two things:

1. Is it **possible** to do this with some variation of the standard Range syntax (i.e., `(x..y).each`)?
2. Either way, what would be the most idiomatic "Ruby way" of accomplishing this (using a Range or otherwise)? Like I said, I'm new to the language; so any guidance you can offer on how to do things in a more typical Ruby style would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can't declare a `Range` with a "step". Ranges don't have steps, they simply have a beginning and an end.

You can certainly *iterate* over a `Range` in steps, for example like this:

```
(2..100).step(2).reverse_each(&method(:p))
```

But if all you want is to iterate, then what do you need the `Range` for in the first place? Why not just iterate?

```
100.step(2, -2, &method(:p))
```

This has the added benefit that unlike `reverse_each` it does not need to generate an intermediate array.

Comment: Nice. Exactly what I needed -- and thanks also for clarifying my terminology. Cleared up a lot!

Comment: @Jörg any idea how you ended up with the last statement? The docs for step mention only one argument, so I was wondering how you worked your way to that succinct way of solving this problem.

Comment: @n_x_l: I'not sure what docs you're looking at, the `step` parameter  is [clearly documented](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-2.1.1/Numeric.html#method-i-step). The oldest docs I could find were the ones for Ruby 1.8.6 and it [was already there](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-1.8.6/Numeric.html#method-i-step) back then in 2007.

Comment: Ah sorry, I was looking at step from range. :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

This question answers yours: [about ruby range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583665/about-ruby-range)

```
(2..100).step(2) do |x|
    # your code
end
```

Comment: So, how would I do it backwards?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue here are the various ways I found to do the same SIMPLE thing I used step in the end because it allowed for NEGATIVE and FRACTIONAL increments and I had no conditions, other than the bounds to look for

```
  case loop_type

    when FOR
      # doen't appear to have a negative or larger than 1 step size!
      for kg in 50..120 do
        kg_to_stones_lbs(kg)
      end

    when STEP
      120.step(70,-0.5){ |kg|
        kg_to_stones_lbs(kg)
      }

    when UPTO
      50.upto(120) { |kg|
        kg_to_stones_lbs(kg)
      }

    when DOWNTO
      120.downto(50){ |kg|
        kg_to_stones_lbs(kg)
      }

    when RANGE
      (50..120).reverse_each{ |kg|
        kg_to_stones_lbs(kg)
      }

    when WHILE
      kg = 120
      while kg >= 50
        kg_to_stones_lbs(kg)
        kg -= 0.5
      end
  end
```

O/P:

92.0kg -  14st  7lbs

91.5kg -  14st  6lbs

91.0kg -  14st  5lbs

90.5kg -  14st  4lbs

90.0kg -  14st  2lbs

89.5kg -  14st  1lbs

89.0kg -  14st  0lbs

88.5kg -  13st 13lbs

88.0kg -  13st 12lbs