# Create array in Ruby with begin value, end value and step for float values

Tags: arrays, ruby, range

How can one create an array filled with values within a range (having a begin and end value) and a step? It should support begin and end values of `float` type.

Comment: If you are looking on how to do this with integer values only, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583665/about-ruby-range or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029785/declaring-an-integer-range-with-step-1-in-ruby and simply call `.to_a` at the end.

Comment: Why `decimal` and not just `float`? I think that's confusing since Ruby has `BigDecimal` as decimal data type.

Comment: @cremno: You're right, I'm updating the wording to only state `float` then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For **floats with custom stepping** you can use [Numeric#step](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Numeric.html#method-i-step) like so:

```
-1.25.step(by: 0.5, to: 1.25).to_a
# => [-1.25, -0.75, -0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 1.25]
```

---

If you are looking on how to do this with **integer values only**, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583665/about-ruby-range) or [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029785/declaring-an-integer-range-with-step-1-in-ruby) on how to create ranges and simply call `.to_a` at the end. Example:

```
(-1..1).step(0.5).to_a
# => [-1.0, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0]
```

Comment: btw, posting the question if you know the answer, not sure it's in the spirit of SO....

Comment: It sure is in the spirit of SO, it's even encouraged to do so, see this post on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Comment: Oh. Makes sense, actually.