# Ruby: How to iterate over a range, but in set increments?

Tags: ruby, iterator, increment

So I'm iterating over a range like so:

```
(1..100).each do |n|
    # n = 1
    # n = 2
    # n = 3
    # n = 4
    # n = 5
end
```

But what I'd like to do is iterate by 10's.

So in stead of increasing `n` by 1, the next `n` would actually be 10, then 20, 30, etc etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583665/about-ruby-range

Comment: @DiegoDias but this has the best and then that thread

Answer (score 287, accepted):

See http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html#M000695 for the full API.

Basically you use the `step()` method.  For example:

```
(10..100).step(10) do |n|
    # n = 10
    # n = 20
    # n = 30
    # ...
end
```

Comment: This answer led me to what I was looking for... If you have two times, you can do `(time1..time2).step(15.minutes) do |time|`

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`Numeric#step`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step).

```
0.step(30,5) do |num|
  puts "number is #{num}"
end
# >> number is 0
# >> number is 5
# >> number is 10
# >> number is 15
# >> number is 20
# >> number is 25
# >> number is 30
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's another, perhaps more familiar-looking way to do it:

```
for i in (0..10).step(2) do
    puts i
end
```

Comment: Sorry, but the ruby style guide strongly discourages the use `for` loops.

Comment: @DarthEgregious why is that?

Comment: It's an extension of the philosophy that every _thing_ is an object and every _action_ is a method call. So rather than using a built-in for looping with `for`, you should use the `each` method.

Answer (score 7):

```
rng.step(n=1) {| obj | block } => rng
```

Iterates over rng, passing each nth element to the block. If the range contains numbers or strings, natural ordering is used. Otherwise step invokes succ to iterate through range elements. The following code uses class Xs, which is defined in the class-level documentation.

```
range = Xs.new(1)..Xs.new(10)
range.step(2) {|x| puts x}
range.step(3) {|x| puts x}
```

produces:

```
1 x
3 xxx
5 xxxxx
7 xxxxxxx
9 xxxxxxxxx
1 x
4 xxxx
7 xxxxxxx
10 xxxxxxxxxx
```

Reference: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html

......