# Problems with Modulo operator Ruby: Why am I getting "undefined method `%' for 1..100:Range"?

Tags: ruby, modulo

For some reason I'm getting the error `undefined method '%' for 1..100:Range` when I run the following code:

```
[1..100].each do |x|
  if x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0
    puts "CracklePop"
  elsif x % 3 == 0
    puts "Crackle"
  elsif x % 5 == 0
    puts "Pop"
  else
    puts x
  end
end
```

Any idea what's going on? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I believe you misspelled ["fizz" and "buzz"](http://blog.adnanmasood.com/2010/04/21/the-fizz-buzz-programming-test/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's the wrong syntax for ranges.

You've made an array with 1 element, and that element is itself the range `1..100`. What you've written is equivalent to `[(1.100)]`. You're iterating over the *outer* array one time, and setting `x` to `(1..100)`

You want `(1..100).each`, which invokes `each` on the range, not on an array *containing* the range.

Answer (score 1):

By doing `[1..100]` you are not looping `from 1 to 100` but on `1..100`, which is a `Range` object, what you really want to do is:-

```
 (1..100).step do |x|
 if x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0
     puts "CracklePop"
 elsif x % 3 == 0
     puts "Crackle"
 elsif x % 5 == 0
     puts "Pop"
 else
     puts x
 end
 end
```

Basically, Range represents an interval, you can iterate over Range as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346335/ruby-how-to-iterate-over-a-range-but-in-set-increments), create an array from Range as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191329/correct-way-to-populate-an-array-with-a-range-in-ruby) and more details on range can be found [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Range.html).

Answer (score -1):

Just as it says. `1..100` does not have a method `%`. The expression `(1..100) % 3` is undefined.