# Generated integer array based on number in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, integer, summarize

I want to generate 5 buttons with different values based on one integer.
For example I've got 30, I want to create buttons with 10 20 30 40 50

```
value = 30
int1 = value - 20
int2 = value - 10
int3 = value
int4 = value + 10
int5 = value + 20

buttoncode = ""
%w{int1 int2 int3 int4 int5}.each do |minutes|
   buttoncode += 'buttoncode'
end
```

I can do it in a very bad way, but it could be done a smarter solution I guess.
Is it possible to make something like that?

```
%w{sum(max-20) sum(max-10) max sum(max+10) sum(max+20)}.each do |minutes|

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Ruby: How to iterate over a range, but in set increments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346335/ruby-how-to-iterate-over-a-range-but-in-set-increments)

So in your case it would be:

```
(min..max).step(10) do |n|
   n += 'buttoncode'
end
```

By the way, this is not really Rails specific, but Ruby specific. Rails is a **web** framework that handles the interaction between browser and the web server that is built on top of Ruby.

If you feel like you aren't that up to speed with Ruby, try https://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ and do some exercise on HackerRank or ProjectEuler in Ruby.

Comment: @RickySpanish np, ProjectEuler has definitely helped me to learn Ruby by doing, so I would recommend it to anyone who would like to practice the basics of a new programming language.